# Whats difference between $.emptyobject and $.plainobject?

Tags: jquery

I Want to know about difference b/w **empty object** and **plain object**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you actually mean to ask about [`$.isEmptyObject()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) and [`$.isPlainObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isplainobject/).

`$.isEmptyObject()` tells you if an object has NO enumerable properties and thus (from the outside) appears to be "empty".  It could be any type of object.

`$.isPlainObject()` tells you if an object is just a plain Javascript object created with `var x= {};` or `var x = new Object()` that has no other inheritance and isn't some sort of host object.

A plain object may or may not be empty.  An empty object may or may not be a plain object.

For example, an `Array` in Javascript is an object, but it is not a plain object according to `$.isPlainObject()` because it derives from something other than just `Object`.

Some examples:

```
$.isPlainObject([]);                     // false
$.isPlainObject({});                     // true
$.isPlainObject({greeting: "hello"});    // true
$.isPlainObject($(document));            // false

$.isEmptyObject([]);                     // true
$.isEmptyObject({});                     // true
$.isEmptyObject([1]);                    // false
$.isEmptyObject({greeting: "hello"});    // false
```